# position: absolute in Safari browser not working

Tags: css, safari, wordpress-theming, css-position

I can't find support for a WordPress theme I'm using so am trying to fix a problem myself.
The problem only occurs with the safari browser. Using safari, blocks of overlaid text do not appear. These are title which should display over the images they relate to.

The page exhibiting the problem is here:
https://annabelmccrory.com/portfolio_category/celebrities-sports-personalities/

The theme part that outputs the contents is here:

```
<div class="item <?php echo ebor_the_terms('portfolio_category', ' ', 'slug'); ?>">
    <figure>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php 
                the_title('<div class="text-overlay"><div class="info"><span>', '</span></div></div>');
            the_post_thumbnail('large');
            ?>
        </a>
    </figure>
</div>
```

The css class that I'm having the problem with is text-overlay. Here's the code for that:

```
figure a .text-overlay {
    opacity: 0.1;    /* Modern browsers */
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    padding: 50px;
    background: #222;
    background: rgba(20,20,20,0.75);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    position: absolute;
}
figure a:hover .text-overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Using the Safari developer tools, I can access the css for the class.

If I toggle the 'position: absolute' off and on - magically, the overlaid text appears. Everything is perfect. Of course, after refreshing the page, it disappears again.

After more investigation, I can see that before I toggle 'position: absolute' off, the div with .text-overlay class is pushed down below the item it is supposed to overlay. When I toggle 'position: absolute' back to on, the div is positioned correctly.
[Before toggling 'position: absolute'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sUvQ.jpg)

[After 'position: absolute'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtPXx.jpg)

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're running into a bit of trouble with how the overlay text is showing up in Safari. From what you've described and the code you provided, I think I can give you a hand with some suggestions to troubleshoot and potentially fix the issue.

Safari's rendering behavior can sometimes be affected by hardware acceleration. Try adding the -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); CSS property to the .text-overlay class. This can trigger hardware acceleration and potentially solve rendering glitches.
You might want to take a look at this part of the code:

```
figure a .text-overlay {
    /* ... existing properties ... */
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Sometimes Safari can be a bit picky with how it renders CSS, so playing around with properties like this might help. I'd recommend checking out a few things:

Since you're using a z-index value of 9999 for the overlay, there's a possibility that it's causing a stacking context issue in Safari.

CSS Properties: Since you mentioned that temporarily changing the position: absolute property seems to help, you could experiment by adjusting or temporarily removing some other properties. It's possible that one of them is causing the problem.

Transitions: Sometimes transitions can behave differently across different browsers. You might want to tweak the transition timings and see if that affects how the text overlay appears. You could try something like this:

```
figure a .text-overlay {
    /* ... existing properties ... */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s, padding 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s, padding 0.4s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.4s, padding 0.4s;
    transition: opacity 0.4s, padding 0.4s;
}
```

Vendor Prefixes: Even though Safari is pretty good with modern CSS, it's a good idea to include vendor prefixes for better compatibility. Double-check that your transition properties have these prefixes.

Updates: Make sure your Safari browser is up to date, and also ensure your WordPress theme is the latest version. Sometimes these kinds of issues can be resolved just by updating things.

JavaScript: If there's any JavaScript affecting the overlay's behavior, it might be worth looking into that. Check if there are any errors or conflicts that could be causing the problem.

Different Safari Versions: If you can, try testing your page on different versions of Safari to see if the issue is specific to certain versions.

And just a quick tip: remember to clear your browser cache while testing these changes. This way, you'll be sure you're seeing the most recent version of your styles.

If none of these suggestions do the trick, you might want to consider getting in touch with the theme developer or reaching out to a WordPress developer community. They might have come across similar issues and could offer some insights.

I not at all a professional but hope this helps! Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you for responding; unfortunately none of your suggestions has resolved the issue.